# How to prevent visual studio 2017 from build javascript?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, webpack, build, visual-studio-2017

I upgraded today to VS2017, and I saw that every time I change something in my my web app project - the build build all my javascript again (I'm using webpack for client).
It is cool, but it take a lot of time, so I'll be happy to configure it to stop building the javascript (and I'll build it myself just when it changed).

Answer (score 69, accepted):

### Simple Answer

In your csproj file, add the following line to the existing PropertyGroup block:

```
<PropertyGroup>
     <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
</PropertyGroup>
```

If adding `.ts` or `.tsx` files to your project causes your project file to be modified, you may need to apply the following fix. See the [bug report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/288648/vs-modifies-csproj-file-with-typescriptcompile-ite.html) for more details.

```
 <ItemGroup>
      <None Remove="**/*.ts;**/*.tsx" />
      <Content Remove="**/*.ts;**/*.tsx" />
      <TypeScriptCompile Include="**/*.ts;**/*.tsx" />
 </ItemGroup>
```

Add a `tsconfig.json` file to your project root and make sure the following setting is set:

```
"compileOnSave": false,
```

Finally, Restart Visual Studio

---

### Details

Nuget creates a generated targets file called `[ProjectName].csproj.nuget.g.targets` in the `obj` directory of your project. This targets file is importing `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web.ProjectSystem.targets` which in turn imports `Microsoft.TypeScript.targets`.

In the `Microsoft.TypeScript.targets` file, the following line has a comment that lets us know that if this property is set to true, then the TypeScript compilation task will do nothing:

```
<!-- Makes the TypeScript compilation task a no-op -->
<TypeScriptCompileBlocked Condition="'$(TypeScriptCompileBlocked)' == ''">false</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
```

Comment: look nice, but didn't worked for me :(, I added this row, but the javascript still compiled...

Comment: Interesting. I was having the same issue as you and this was what solved it for me. I put the `TypeScriptCompileBlocked` element directly under the `RuntimeIdentifier` element. I also am including my typescript files as content like this `<Content Include="**\*.ts" Exclude="$(GlobalExclude)" />`. Can you post the `PropertyGroup` section of your csproj file?

Comment: Please see my updated answer. In my project, I am also telling Visual Studio to disable compile on save via the `tsconfig.json`

Comment: in my case I saw now that it's another story. I found that in my csproj that it should compile js on "release mode", and this was my state... probably it's the default. I dont have most of the configs and files you mentioned. however, I'll check your answer :) thanks

Comment: Is `disableCompileOnSave` an undocumented option? Can't find it in the documentation.

Comment: `compileOnSave` is part of the tsconfig, not the project file, and is documented [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html)

Comment: @ChristopherHaws Should your answer say `"compileOnSave": false` instead of `"disableCompileOnSave": true`

Comment: @tjrobinson Yes, it looks like they may have changed it in the TS 1.8 release. I updated my answer to reflect the change. Thanks for pointing that out. Here is the github discussion around it: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2326

Comment: go to Tools -> Extensions & Updates, and **disable** `Typescript for Microsoft Visual Studio` completely.

Comment: Where does the "<Content Include="**\*.ts" Exclude="$(GlobalExclude)" />" goes to? Inside "Item Group"?

Comment: @SkorunkaFrantišek It should go into any `PropertyGroup` that will be evaluated. Generally, I put it in the first `PropertyGroup` which contains items such as `AssemblyName` and `OutputType`.

Comment: For those not using TypeScript at all in their project, Burak Tasci got the right solution.

Comment: @ChristopherHaws - I have found that adding `<Content Include="**\*.ts" Exclude="$(GlobalExclude)" />` is unnecessary and as of VS2017 15.3, this inclusion butts heads with the fact that including files from `wwwroot` is done by default. If you add this line you'll get a bunch of **duplicate content** errors upon building. It appears that line tries to exclude `$(GlobalExclude)` but in my `.csproj` that's undefined. I just removed this inclusion and it worked as desired.  See: https://www.danielcrabtree.com/blog/273/fixing-the-duplicate-content-error-after-upgrading-visual-studio-2017

Answer (score 3):

I'm using webpack's ts-loader to compile and bundle my TypeScript files. So I no longer needed the automatic compilation that Visual Studio performed on each build. In Visual Studio 2017, I just commented out the following line from tsconfig.json to stop the automatic compilation:

```
"outDir": "./wwwroot/build/",
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem - Webpack was rebuilding my Typescript files every time  Visual Studio rebuilt the project, despite having

```
<TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
```

in my proj file, and

```
"compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false
```

in my tsconfig.json file.

Turns out it was because I had the NPM Task Runner VS extension installed (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.NPMTaskRunner), and in Task Runner Explorer this had a build task bound to the 'Before Build' event. I didn't need this extension so I just uninstalled it.

Note: I didn't need Webpack to rebuild on VS build because I had it watching my files and rebuilding anyway as I made changes, via this extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebPackTaskRunner

Answer (score 3):

Setting `TypeScriptCompileBlocked` to `true` was not enough for me. What worked was going to the project properties - there is a TypeScript Build tab where you can configure TS compilation, including the Compile On Save option:

[image]

It results in the following getting added to the `csproj` file:

```
<TypeScriptTarget>ES5</TypeScriptTarget>
<TypeScriptJSXEmit>None</TypeScriptJSXEmit>
<TypeScriptModuleKind>ES6</TypeScriptModuleKind>
<TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>False</TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>
<TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>False</TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>
<TypeScriptRemoveComments>False</TypeScriptRemoveComments>
<TypeScriptOutFile />
<TypeScriptOutDir />
<TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>False</TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>
<TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>True</TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>
<TypeScriptSourceMap>True</TypeScriptSourceMap>
<TypeScriptMapRoot />
<TypeScriptSourceRoot />
```

Answer (score 1):

**Errors complaining about .ts files:**
I got build error when I tried to rebuild a VS2017 Web project that includes some typescript files. Error looked like these
`Error  TS1005  (TS) '?' expected.  C:\...\...project1 (tsconfig or jsconfig project)   C:\\...\...project1 \node_modules\@storybook\addon-knobs\dist\type-defs.d.ts`

**No answers that really helped..so far:**
After spending hours searching up and down the Stack or else, I realized it could be as simple as to compare the errored project file to another one that also has typescript but no compile error.

**It is simple..but it worked:**

Here are the steps:

1. Unload the projects and edited Project file
2. Search "TypeScript" (exact case and exact word option) and found two Imports that matched:

   `<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props')" />`

`<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets')" />`

3. Then I went to the Project that did not have a problem compiling .ts files and look, it's different in the Condition:

   `<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" Condition="false" />`
4. So I just replaced the Import with the one in 3) and reloaded the project and as expected, compiled successfully.

In the perfect world,**Condition="Exists**('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets')" might just be exactly same as **Condition="false"** but there were not, even in my machine there is no such folder existing (C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\15.0).

Sometimes, common sense helps more than deep knowledge, and this was that time.

Answer (score 1):

In my case (Visual Studio 2017 15.9.25), I have to add the following property to .csproj

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>false</TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>
</PropertyGroup>
```

More details:

I read this article https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options-in-msbuild.html and realize that VS will build TS based on the file **Microsoft.TypeScript.targets**.

And in this file, I see that it also bases on this property to control the Compile-on-Save `TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled`. So setting this property to `false` in .csproj will stop the compile typescript when saving. (Please note that before doing this I already tried setting `"compileOnSave": false` in tsconfig.json file but it did not help)

Answer (score 0):

Done the following setting along with TypeScriptCompileBlocked to true.

Set the below condition to false in .csproj file of the application.

Comment: Sorry, which condition?