# Ignore TS7027 warnings from third-party javascript files in VS2017?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2017

I have a project using Handlebars, and Visual Studio 2017 is displaying dozens of "TS7027: Unreachable code detected" warnings from the Handlebars js files. I'm not even using Typescript in this project, so it's not clear why this error is appearing, but it's a real problem since I have to filter through nearly 50 TS7027 warnings to find warnings that are actually pertinent. So, is there a way to ignore these warnings (I'm guessing not, after some Googling), or better, tell Typescript not to parse any of my .js files?

Edit:
I followed the instructions in the answer to this question ([How to prevent visual studio 2017 from build javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40667665/how-to-prevent-visual-studio-2017-from-build-javascript)), but still seeing the warnings. They present when the project is first opened, before I explicitly save or build, so disabling TS compilation on save/build doesn't seem to be a solution for this. As a workaround, I've disabled the TypeScript extension in VS2017.

Comment: Very annoying issue.  I'll disable TypeScript extension as well as a work-around...

Comment: Just ran into this also, very annoying.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from your question you want to supress *all TS7027 warnings*, for a specific project. That scenario can be done in Visual Studio like so:

1. In Visual Studio, select your project > Properties > Build
2. In the *Errors and Warnings* section, provide a **comma-seperated** list of all warnings to supress

See this screenshot for your case:

[image: Suppress specific warnings in Visual Studio 2017]

This solves the problem by ignoring these specific warnings - for that specific project.

Now if you want to **block/disable TypeScript compiling entirely** for that specific project, you might want to add the following line to your .csproj in the PropertyGroup section:

```
<TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
```

More detailed info about this can be found in the [How to prevent visual studio 2017 from build javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40708463/1039247) question, here on StackOverflow.