# How to stop Typescript compiler from generating JS and JS.MAP files in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

I have a few **typescript** files for my app `myapp` in my **Visual Studio 2017 ASP.NET** project. I use a **gulp** task to generate the JS files, so I don't want the build or language service creating these **JS and JS.MAP** files.

This is how my TSCONFIG file look like:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "types": [ "" ],
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "./myapp/**/*"
  ]
}
```

I tried the following:

1. I added the `myapp` to the `exclude` section of the **tsconfig.js**. Both the **js and js.map** are not generated at that time if I close Visual Studio and open again. But I see a lot of compilation errors.
2. I added `<TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>` to the `.csproj` file. I closed VS 2017, opened again and did a build. I see the JS and JS.MAP files.
3. I changed the `BuildAction` property to none, but still see the JS and JS.MAP files

[image]

What should I do so the syntax check of the TS file will work but does not generate any JS and JS.MAP files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent visual studio 2017 from build javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40667665/how-to-prevent-visual-studio-2017-from-build-javascript)

Comment: The issue I have is different. I don't do a *build* option from the menu from Visual Studion. I just close and open the project and start seeing these behaviors.

Comment: I know this is a bit old, but if your problem is mainly the js.map, you can just set sourceMap to false on tsconfig

Comment: @wonderfulworld Did you found any solution?

Comment: @wonderfulworld your VS is actually running TSC command each time to check for TS errors (it reads tsconfig.json) which without "noEmit": true will output JS files to your folder...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that if I created the file using angular it didn't emit a .js but if I added a new TypeScript file from Visual Studio via the New Item menu it did. Turns out the latter sets the Build Action to "TypeScript file" whereas the former sets the build action to None, Do Not Copy. I changed the offending TypeScript files to None and it's stopped the .js files being generated. This is contrary to the OPs statement that it had no affect - but in my case it worked. Setting noEmit: true just resulted in no vendor.js file being generated for my angular ng build.

Answer (score 14):

Try add `"noEmit": true` in your `tsconfig`. It should prevent the .js .js.map from generating.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, do you know of any reason why this would be the case?

Comment: @ChristopherThomas Check your typescript version, if it's older than 4.0 then there's a flag called `"incremental": true` that confict with `"noEmit": true`

Comment: also works in VS Code

Answer (score 4):

Try add `"noEmitOnError": true` in your tsconfig. It should prevent the .js .js.map from generating if there is any error in the TS files(s).

Answer (score 3):

If Visual Studio seems to be ignoring the noemit option in the tsconfig file, edit your project file.  In the project file, go to the `<PropertyGroup>` that contains the rest of the TypeScript options and add `<TypeScriptNoEmit>True</TypeScriptNoEmit>` between that PropertyGroup's open and closing tags.

Comment: This one did it for me. NOTE: You may need to restart VS after changing the project file for the changes to take effect.

Comment: works in VS2022 without restart (just reload project), thanks

Answer (score 0):

My issue was I had accidentally deleted "outDir" from my `tsconfig.json`.

To fix, I added the line back in:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "outDir": "./dist",
    ...
  }
}
```

From the [Typescript Docs - Out Dir](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#outDir):

> If specified, `.js` (as well as `.d.ts`, `.js.map`, etc.) files will be emitted into this directory. The directory structure of the original source files is preserved; see [rootDir](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#rootDir) if the computed root is not what you intended.

> If not specified, `.js` files will be emitted in the same directory as the `.ts` files they were generated from