# Typescript export not being found by one project , but is found by another

Tags: typescript

Using the helpful guide [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47729344) I have extracted some code which is common to client and server projects into a new separate project  (in VS Code). Both server and client should import classes etc from the shared project.
The server is working fine - it has

```
import { apiMethods, User } from '../ridehub-common'
```

and it's quite happy using both `apiMethods` (an enum) and `User` (a class), and intellisense works perfectly.

In the client project I have

```
import { apiMethods } from '../../../ridehub-common'
```

but when the code is run I get an error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError SyntaxError: The requested module '/@fs/C:/Users/quilk/source/repos/ridehub-common/index.js' does not provide an export named 'apiMethods'
    at (program) (c:\Users\quilk\source\repos\ridehub\src\utils\ridedata.ts:4:10)
```

Also a similar error if I try to use `User`. I'm at a loss to understand how `ridehub-common` provides the export to the server but not to the client. Furthermore I would have thought that such an error would be shown by the TS compiler, not when the code is executed (the error occurs before any breakpoint that I can set).

Both projects have this in `tsconfig.json`:

```
  { 
      "path": "../ridehub-common",
  }
```

and after making any change in the common project I have run `tsc -b` in all three projects to update the exports & imports.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer (sort of) was found in the error message:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError SyntaxError: The requested module '/@fs/C:/Users/quilk/source/repos/ridehub-common/index.js' does not provide an export named 'apiMethods'
    at (program) (c:\Users\quilk\source\repos\ridehub\src\utils\ridedata.ts:4:10)
```

"**../index.js'** does not provide an export..." - no it doesn't because the import should be looking at `index.ts` not `index.js`.

The TS compile command `tsc -b` creates loads of `.js` and `.js.map` files in my working directory. Deleting these solved the problem. But this is a very messy method.

I have now discovered how to stop these files from being saved in the first place: add `"noEmit": true` to  tsconfig. Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45919249).